# Returning Json through ActionResult return type action or JsonResult return type action. Which one is lightweight or fast?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

An interviewer asked me this question. As far as my understanding of MVC architecture goes, that ActionResult is an abstract class from which all classes inherit.

But he asked specifically that which one of the action will be lightweight?

```
public ActionResult ar() { return Json(); }
```

OR

```
public JsonResult ar() { return Json(); }
```

Comment: What does lightweight mean in this context?

Comment: How did you answer it?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not the biggest C# or MVC expert, but, **this is a trick question**.

**They are the same.**

You are correct that ActionResult is an abstract class and JsonResult inherits from it.

Comment: There is no differents which type returns action `ActionResult` or `JsonResult`, the code will be the same: `return new Json(your object)`;

Comment: +1 @Alexander. Now we just wait for Eric Lippert, Jon Skeet, Jon Galloway, Haack, Wilson, Hanselman etc to confirm/deny :)

Answer (score 2):

@Lakshay you answered correctly, the fact that one returns JSON and the other doesn't excplictly doesn't mean anything. If the JSON returned is identical the `public JsonResult ar() { return Json(); }` will be slightly faster in crazy time ... meaning it won't.

Your interviewer was one of the guys who was over his head - don't accept a job in this place. Really, if he asks you a question like this, it only indicates .. he didn't know either OR worse he though he knew. Which is likely the case.

You gave the best answer to a stupid question (kind of like the MS or Google questions used to be).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer "I don't know" is indeed a good one. Perhaps the interviewer was looking for your attitude or reaction to a nonsensical question. Sure enough you can use `ActionResult` to return Json object, but then you have to do all the associated work manually. For instance, you will have to assign the correct ContentType. `JsonResult` is there to do all this work for you behind the scenes.